# Migrate existing Maildir to Dovecot Maildir sub folder

Tags: postfix, dovecot, maildir

I have an existing Maildir (one file per message) from a backup:

```
root@host:/var/vmail/myname/cur# ls -lha | head -n 7
total 347M
drwx------ 2 vmail vmail 844K Nov  5 10:15 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 vmail vmail 4.0K Jul 17  2022 ..
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  550 Jul 17  2022 1658056227.Vfe02I100442M730331.mx.example.org:2,S
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  556 Jul 17  2022 1658046702.Vfe02I1004e4M425558.mx.example.org:2,S
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  556 Jul 17  2022 1658062217.Vfe02I10056cM929192.mx.example.org:2,
-rw------- 1 vmail vmail  558 Jul 17  2022 1658061684.Vfe02I10056fM171780.mx.example.org:2,
```

The Maildir was written by Postfix for a local mail account.

Now I have a Dovecot IMAP server and a new Maildir.

I'd like to have the old Maildir mails in a subfolder of my new Maildir, e.g. "Backup2022" (`.../Maildir/.Backup2022/cur/`).

How can I import the existing Maildir into a subfolder of my new Dovecot Maildir?

Basically it should be possible by just copying `cp` the existing files into the new folder.

But Dovecot seems to use a different file name format, e.g. `'1699171106.M235687P52052.dovecotsrv,S=1272,W=1295:2,S'`.

So I don't know if I break my new Dovecot Maildir if I just copy the old mails? Can I have Dovecot "import" the existing Maildir somehow?